# cloud raspberry pi

Tags: server, mysql, database

Basically, on the cloud, I want to execute a query and then take/emit result of the evaluation. To simplicity, I want use raspberry Pi as cloud server which stores database tables and can execute queries coming from cloud and send results back.

I am a bit confused  about where I should start. I have some questions, some of them may be vague. Please say me so that I will delete or improve

- are there any open source project which I can use for my purpose ?
- is it possible that I can use the raspberry pi as cloud server and accepts queries ?
- are there any similar project which I can take as a reference ?
- In order to use raspberry pi as cloud server, basically what should I do ?

Again,

some of them may be vague. Please say me so that I will delete or improve

EDIT: Basic sketch

```
    raspberry pi
   |----------|    /--------\
   |          |   /          \     *query send
   | *execute |  -  cloud     -    *see result of query 
   |    query |   \           /    
   |          |    \---------/   
   |----------|                    user
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate what you are trying to solve, what you mean by cloud server and what kinds of queries you intend to run. Depending on how I interpret your question I would advise you how to install a cloud stack, a distributed computing solution (like `openmp`, `mpi`) or maybe a database system for `sql` queries. Acarter even came up with http queries, so as it stands your question is somehwat impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, you want to use your Pi as a webserver. This is totally possible, however a 24/7 internet and power connection will probably shorten the life of your Pi, and you must realise that with the limited RAM and CPU, accessing the server will probably be very slow, especially if many people are accessing it.

To start with, you will need an application that handles incoming requests and returns the results. Try [apache](http://apache.org) or [nginx](http://nginx.org).

Then, you mention databases. SQL is the most commonly used database querying format, with [mysql](http://mysql.com) being the most popular PHP integration.

To sum up, configuring your Pi as a webserver will be tricky and slow, but should definately be possible. (After all 90% of all webservers run Linux, many of them with a simiar Debian distribution to the Pi's raspbian.)

Comment: could you please elaborate regarding: "a 24/7 internet and power connection will probably shorten the life of your Pi"? Is there any particular pattern of internet and power use that leads to the shorter life span and what is the life expectancy in that situation?

Comment: @lenik I'm not an expert on this, but generally using something heavily 24/day, with a constant power supply tends to wear it down. I wouldn't have any figures, sorry. After all, the pi is built targetting people who might use it for a few hours a week for a bit of fun, not for serious, constant work.